# How to access iterators in helper for loop functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm attempting to create a helper function that allows me to make nested for loops easily. In my particular script I have a lot of 2D arrays to work with.

```
function array2D(iLen,jLen, callback){
   var i, j;
   for( i =0; i <iLen; i++){ 
       for( j= 0; j <jLen; j++){
          callback();
       }
  }
}
```

How do I rewrite the function if I wanted to access the *i* or *j* iterators in the callback function? For instance, if I wanted to pass the following into array2D:

```
function(){
   console.log(i +" "+j);
}
```

I attempted to create setter functions within **array2D()** but the problem is returning i or j prevents the function operation from completing.

Comment: You simply pass the values to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Call callback with `i` and `j`

```
function array2D(iLen,jLen, callback){
    var i, j;
    for( i =0; i <iLen; i++){ 
        for( j= 0; j <jLen; j++){
            callback(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

And use:

```
array2D(10, 20, function(i,j){
    console.log(i+' '+j)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define you function as:

```
var callback = function(i,j){
    console.log(i +" "+j);
}
```

and then pass it as you already have done. And at the point where you call the callback, you have to pass the arguments.

```
callback(i,j);
```

```js
var callback = function(i,j){
    document.write(i +" "+j+"</br>");
}

function array2D(iLen,jLen, callback){
   var i, j;
   for( i =0; i <iLen; i++){ 
       for( j= 0; j <jLen; j++){
          callback(i,j);
       }
  }
}

array2D(3,4,callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arguments`

```
callback(i, j);
```

---

```
function() {
   console.log(arguments);
}
```